# jQuery prototype using $(this) and this

Tags: jquery, oop, prototype, this, bind

I'm building a jQuery/javascript web application using jQuery `.prototype`.
In the following code I want to update to prototypes global value `this.score`, I'll have to `bind(this)` to make this work.

Without binding `this` I can reach the span inside `btnElement` with `$(this)`, but after binding this doesn't work anymore. Is there any workaround for something like 'this'? ;)

```
showQuestion: function(question) {
   this.quiz.show();

   var btnElement = this.quiz.find('div');
   btnElement.on('click', function() {
        var btn = $(this).find('span');

        if (btn.hasClass('correct')) {
            btn.addClass('good');
            this.score += 1;
        } else {
            $('span.correct').addClass('good');
            btn.addClass('wrong');
        }
   }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've bound your event callback, so `this` within it refers to what `this` outside it referred to. That means you can't use the usual meaning `this` has within jQuery event handlers (the DOM element related to the event).

Three ways to handle that:

1. Use `btnElement` instead, since you have it handy:

   ```
   showQuestion: function(question) {
      this.quiz.show();

      var btnElement = this.quiz.find('div');
      btnElement.on('click', function() {
           var btn = btnElement.find('span');   // <====

           if (btn.hasClass('correct')) {
               btn.addClass('good');
               this.score += 1;
           } else {
               $('span.correct').addClass('good');
               btn.addClass('wrong');
           }
      }.bind(this));
   }
   ```
2. Use [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/), which is the same thing `this` would have been if the handler weren't bound (in this case, you could also use [`e.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) because it's not a delegated handler and so it's the same value):

   ```
   showQuestion: function(question) {
      this.quiz.show();

      var btnElement = this.quiz.find('div');
      btnElement.on('click', function(e) {              // <====
           var btn = $(e.currentTarget).find('span');   // <====

           if (btn.hasClass('correct')) {
               btn.addClass('good');
               this.score += 1;
           } else {
               $('span.correct').addClass('good');
               btn.addClass('wrong');
           }
      }.bind(this));
   }
   ```

   I haven't recommended `e.target` because it's not *quite* the same thing: `e.target` is the element where the event occurred; `this` is the element you had the event hooked on. So `e.target` may be a *descendant* element of your quiz's `div`.
3. Don't bind the event handler, and instead store a reference to `this` in a variable the event handler closes over:

   ```
   showQuestion: function(question) {
      var self = this;                        // <====

      self.quiz.show();

      var btnElement = this.quiz.find('div');
      btnElement.on('click', function() {
           var btn = $(this).find('span');

           if (btn.hasClass('correct')) {
               btn.addClass('good');
               self.score += 1;                // <====
           } else {
               $('span.correct').addClass('good');
               btn.addClass('wrong');
           }
      });                                      // <====
   }
   ```

Comment: Instead of `e.target`, it should be `e.delegateTarget` i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff: Ooooh! I always forget about jQuery's `delegateTarget`!

Comment: @A.Wolff: Although actually, `e.currentTarget` would be most suitable -- but I always forget about `currentTarget` as well, so thanks again. But yes, `e.delegateTarget` is the same as `e.currentTarget` in a non-delegated handler.

Comment: Ya, makes more sense indeed

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! It totally makes sense and it works perfectly fine! Btw. I've used your e.currentTarget solution ;)

Comment: Just quick question about above. Is the third example recommend or is this a hack?

Comment: @ronnyrr: Nothing wrong with the third example, it's very common practice. But for this, I would lean toward #2, as you make it at least *possible* for the JavaScript compiler (the browser is likely to have a just-in-time compiler, rather than an interpreter) to reclaim the memory for the context of the function call to `showQuestion`, even though technically you have a closure there that survives the call (and so would normally retain it): You're not using `btnQuestion` or `question` inside your handler, so a really smart engine may be able to optimize that away. But it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: Thanks, clear! For this example I've removed some code inside the function containing the question parameter.

Comment: @ronnyrr: I figured. :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to *NOT* bind and use a reference to `this` outside the click handler

```
showQuestion: function(question) {
   this.quiz.show();

   var btnElement = this.quiz.find('div');
   var self = this; // create a reference to this
   btnElement.on('click', function() {
        var btn = $(this).find('span'); // you will still be able to find the span which is inside the btnElement

        if (btn.hasClass('correct')) {
            btn.addClass('good');
            self.score += 1; // you will still be able to refer this which is reference as self outside
        } else {
            $('span.correct').addClass('good');
            btn.addClass('wrong');
        }
   });
}
```

Other way is to send a parameter to `bind` *(Apart from all the other options in the other answers)*

```
showQuestion: function(question) {
   this.quiz.show();

   var btnElement = this.quiz.find('div');
   btnElement.on('click', function(event, btnElement) { // 
        var btn = btnElement.find('span'); 
        if (btn.hasClass('correct')) {
            btn.addClass('good');
            this.score += 1; 
        } else {
            $('span.correct').addClass('good');
            btn.addClass('wrong');
        }
   }.bind(this, btnElement));
}
```

This works too just that it is a bit weird to send the button reference to its own click handler.

Comment: Awesome workaround, thanks for solving my problem! ;)